# how to get proper stack trace instead of reflection stack trace?

Tags: java, reflection, stack-trace

I have a big red5 project and it seems that at some point a function is being executed. I tried finding in my code how come this specific function is being executed at that point and I couldn't find it. I want to find out what's calling it.

I read through the answers in stackoverflow and I found the following to show stack trace information of current position.

```
    StackTraceElement[] elements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    for (int i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {
        log.error(elements[i].toString());
    }
```

and I received the following output:

```
java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1479)
component.lobby.LobbyMysql.getChallenges(LobbyComponentMysql.java:76)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanMap.get(BeanMap.java:390)
org.red5.io.amf.Output.writeObject(Output.java:357)
org.red5.io.object.Serializer.writeObjectType(Serializer.java:300)
org.red5.io.object.Serializer.writeComplex(Serializer.java:140)
org.red5.io.object.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:86)
org.red5.io.amf.Output.writeObject(Output.java:357)
org.red5.io.object.Serializer.writeObjectType(Serializer.java:300)
org.red5.io.object.Serializer.writeComplex(Serializer.java:140)
org.red5.io.object.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:86)
...
```

I do get the name of the function that being executed but the top levels for some reason are reflection classes. is there a way to find out the actual method that is calling this specific function ?

I'm not to Java and reflections so please bear with me :)

thanks

Comment: To answer why it is calling that method, I believe it is trying to serialize the object, and therefore is calling all the getters in your class to get the current state.  It does this using reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, the "actual" code *is* using reflection, so that's what you're going to see in the stack trace.

If you can run the code in debug mode, use a breakpoint instead of printing a stack trace. When the breakpoint is hit, look at what's happening in the suspended thread's call stack, specifically around this level:

```
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```